# how to prevent useEffect trigger from the previous screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have 2 screens, on my first screen I have a useEffect which has a watcher on a redux state.

Screen 1

```
...
useEffect(() => {
  if (props.data) {
    navigation.navigate('To Other Screen');
  }
}, [props.data]);
...
```

Then on my second Screen.
I have a function that will update the redux 'data'.
Then, the useEffect on the previous was triggered.

How will I prevent this one.
Thank you.

Comment: How about unmount screen 1 when you navigate away from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this hoc on the react-nativgation and combine this with useEffect;

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/with-navigation-focus/

```
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation';

...

const Page = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.isFocused) {
            // function call;
        }

    }, [props.isFocused]);

};

export default withNavigationFocus(Page);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    if(props.data){
      navigation.navigate('To Other Screen')
    }
  })

  return unsubscribe
}, [navigation, props.data])
```